# How to use ng-options with a dictionary style object?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a data source that looks like this:

```
var options = {
    "A": { name: "Bob", SSN: "111-22-3333" },
    "B": { name: "Sue", SSN: "444-55-6666" }
};
```

I want to use ng-options to let the user select a person from options above.

I've written HTML that looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.selectedPerson" ng-options="label for (value, label) in ctrl.options"></select>
```

This results in my being able to select an option, but it shows [object Object] as the select text for each option.

I believe that the problem is that I need to specify that I want to display the name field for the options, but I'm totally confused about the syntax for the ng-options attribute.

How do I use ng-options with this dictionary-style data source?

Comment: In retrospect, it looks like Angular is designed to work with arrays rather than dictionaries.  It will work here, but I've had issues using other features of Angular with dictionaries, such as filtering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close on the syntax - it's `value as text for (key, val) in obj` - so yours would be:

```
ng-options="label as label.name for (value, label) in ctrl.options"
```

The `name` property of each object would be the text in the above example - while the value is the entire object.

Comment: Thanks.  That was exactly what I needed.  Suppose that the boss came and said that he wanted the selected value to be the SSN.  Is there an easy way to specify what the option value should be, as well?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon -- Yeah - change `label` to `label.SSN` - so the new options become: `label.SSN as label.name for (value, label) in ctrl.options` - to preselect an option - just set the `ngModel` on the select to the SSN you want selected.

Comment: Thanks.  But in that case, it looks like both the option label and the option value are taken from the label in (value, label).  What does the "value" in (value, label) then stand for?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon -- The `value` above is the object key. `{"A":{}, "B":{}}` - `value` will be `A` or `B`